# Java .jar file will run in the command line, but not when being clicked

Tags: java, cmd, executable-jar

I know that issues with executing .jar files have been covered before (as I have read and searched though several threads before posting) but this one is a  *little* bit different. My .jar runs when hit with,

```
java -jre [Jar Name].jar
```

But it will not run when I click on it.

Ok, so I am presently running on JDK 1.6.0_30. Typing in,

```
java -version
```

into the cmd provides that much, and all the code in question was compiled therein under that JDK. Also, within my environmental variables, "Path" points towards

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\\bin;
```

so that is fine as well.

Thinking that it was a problem with how my computer recogizes .jar files, I typed in,

```
ftype|find "jarfile"
```

But that also appers to be fine, as it addresses,

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

which is what it suppose to do, I believe.

My code doesn't terminate unless the user inputs it to do so, so I know that the problem isn't my code running and then closing the command line upon completion either. It doesn't open the cmd or error at all. What other nuiance to .jar files and Java am I overlooking here?

Comment: Well it looks like Windows file association is using the JRE while the command line `java` command is using the JDK. Might that be the problem?

Comment: Did you specify your main class when creating the jar? See [link](http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html)

Comment: Do you have the MainClass value in your Manifest file in the Jar? What happens when you run it from the command line with javaw.exe? Is that the command that works or just plain java.exe?

Comment: Yup, main class is specified. It runs in the command line after all, just not when clicked. Also, trutheality, what exactly do you mean? Should I have Path pointing towards the jre, or am I mistaken?

Comment: To Logan; Actually, when I run it with javaw -jar [Jar Name].jar nothing happens as well. So it looks like just plain java.exe

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have forced .jar files to run when I double-click them in Windows 7 by:

1. Right-click .jar file, choose "Open With" context menu option
2. Browse to and choose java.exe as the process to open the .jar file with
3. Check the option to "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" so that in the future any time I double-click a .jar file it is executed.

Likewise, I've done this same process but have chosen to open the .jar file with a Zip utility (e.g,. 7-Zip) so that my .jar files are treated like .zip files because 99% I'm wanting to examine its contents rather than run them.